How to connect createListenerMiddleware with RTK Query endpoints call?
I have an app written in react, typescript and redux toolkit.
I have view of users list. This list is paginated, sortable and you can filter the results by search query (e.g. user's name). In this component, I fetch the list of users using the endpoint included in the rtk query:
export const UsersList = () => {
  const data = useGetUsersQuery({ page: 0 });

   return <Table users={data} />
}

Endpoint in userApi.ts:
const usersApi = api.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: (build) => ({
    getUsers: build.query<UsersResponseTypes, UserRequestTypes>({
      query: ({  page = 1, searchQuery }) => {
        return ${ENDPOINTS.USERS}?page=${page}&q=${searchQuery};
      },
    }),
  }),
});

export const { useGetUsersQuery } = usersApi;

I also use createListenerMiddleware to listen for changes to the page or searchQuery parameters:
const listenerMiddleware = createListenerMiddleware();

listenerMiddleware.startListening({
    predicate: { ... }, // not important here
      effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {
       listenerApi.dispatch(
          usersApi.endpoints.getUsers.initiate({ page: action.payload.page, searchQuery: action.payload.searchQuery })
      );
  },
})

In the network tab in the browser I see that this request is being executed and correct data is coming. But view does not refresh. As if the cache was not validated or the component did not receive information that data had been changed.
I tried various options, but none of them brought the expected result.
Could I kindly ask for help with this issue?
I tried the various options indicated in the redux toolkit documentation. I'm wondering if it's at all possible to combine createListenerMiddleware with RTK Query, or if it's just for actions in the store, without the ability to make requests to the api.
I would expect that when the page in the application changes from 0 to 1, 1 to 2, etc., this createListenerMiddleware would fire up and do the data invalidation and this current data would be displayed on the view.

It's unclear what you are saying is an issue or problem. Are you saying the middleware listener is not working as expected when some action is dispatched? It seems like you say it is working as expected since network requests are initiated. If this is correct, can you [edit] to clarify what "view" you are expecting to be updated? The UsersList component using a different request?

Hi Drew, you understood my problem well. The point is that the UsersList is a paginated table. When I change the page from 1 to 2 or 2 to 3 etc. then the information about the current page is stored in redux store. At this point, the listener fires because I have createListenerMiddleware added. And I can see in the network tab that this request is executed. However, the UsersList view does not update. That is, for example, I go from page 1 to 2 and the list continues as if I were on page 1, even though the request has executed and returned data that should be on page 2.

You've hardcoded the useGetUsersQuery query to use page 0. Something in UsersList needs to update the page argument passed to the query hook.

No, no. It's not like that. In the example, I gave a very truncated code so as to indicate only the most relevant issues.
In reality, I have there:
const currentPageIndex = useAppSelector((state) => state.pagination);
and the call to the useGetUsersQuery hookup looks like this:
const data = useGetUsersQuery({ page: currentPageIndex });

I see, well that makes a bit more sense. At this point I'm maybe not understanding what you are trying to accomplish here with this middleware listener to initiate the same query endpoints that your UI creates subscriptions for. If the UI is using the useGetUsersQuery hook I don't see any need for the middleware. Can you [edit] to clarify the use case and what you are trying to achieve?

Our discussion worked like “rubber duck debugging” :)
I myself began to wonder if this listener is needed at all. However, I need to use this listener because there is way too much logic in the react component related to switching between pages, searching and sorting. I figured that moving this logic to createListenerMiddleware would be a better solution.
Then I have one more question. Is this call to api in this listener a proper way: ?
listenerApi.dispatch(
      farmersApi.endpoints.getFarmers.initiate({ page: paginationState, searchQuery: searchQueryState })
    );


That isn't an incorrect method of initiating a query endpoint, by that I mean, yes, that is how you manually initiate an endpoint. It doesn't create a subscription (AFAIK), but will trigger a query to be made and cached, and if/when the UI makes the same query with the same args, if there is already a cached result it will use it. Outside this I still don't know what or why you'd use a middleware listener like this. Happy to have helped however I have though.

@BartoszButrym, I have exactly the same issue.
Did you find any solution to your problem?

@abhiox Unfortunately not. I gave up on this solution.

It looks like you are not passing the actual data to the users prop. Actually, you are passing the object that the hook return, which includes data, isFetching, isLoading, etc. See the signature of the useQuery hook here: https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/api/created-api/hooks#signature
Instead of doing this:
export const UsersList = () => {
  const data = useGetUsersQuery({ page: 0 });

   return <Table users={data} />
}

I assume you want to destruct the data from the object like this:
export const UsersList = () => {
  const {data} = useGetUsersQuery({ page: 0 });

   return <Table users={data} />
}

This is probably the reason why you are not seeing the data on the Table component and not because the listener is not well implemented.
